# Value are assigned to wrong label

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I am currently working on implementing a bar chart using 
[Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) API on a website developed in ASP.NET. I have managed to display the chart with the values. I am getting these values from a backend database. The values are as following;

**Course:** Set to *Retail* in DB

**Progression:** Set to *120* in DB

Now the problem I'm having is when the barchart is displayed on the page its as following;

[image]

The course gets the Progression value.

To bind the data to the chart The code is below

```
private void BindChart()
{
    DataTable dsChartData = new DataTable();
    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        dsChartData = GetChartData();

        strScript.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>  
                google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']}); </script>  

                <script type='text/javascript'>  

                function drawChart() {         
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                ['Progression', 'Course'],");

        foreach (DataRow row in dsChartData.Rows)
        {
            strScript.Append("['" + row["Course"] + "'," + row["Progression"] + "],");
        }
        strScript.Remove(strScript.Length - 1, 1);
        strScript.Append("]);");

        strScript.Append(@" var options = {     
                                hAxis: {
                                viewWindow: {
                                min: 0,
                                max: 100
                                },
                                ticks: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                                },
                                title: 'My Progression (%)'      
                                };   ");

        strScript.Append(@"var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart'));          
                            chart.draw(data, options);        
                            }    
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
                        ");
        strScript.Append(" </script>");

        ltScripts.Text = strScript.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        dsChartData.Dispose();
        strScript.Clear();
    }
}
```

And to get the data from the database I'm using the below code

```
private DataTable GetChartData()
{
    string UsrName = User.Identity.Name;
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Progression,Course FROM Messages where UserName=@UserName"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("UserName", UsrName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(para);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return dt.Tables[0];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @Downvoter care to say why?

Comment: Not sure why. I don't think you could have made this question clearer or provided more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mostly there, but you need to just swap the column names at the start of your array and then leave the rest as-is:

```
strScript.Append(@"[...]
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
            ['Course', 'Progression'],");

foreach (DataRow row in dsChartData.Rows)
{
  strScript.Append("['" + row["Course"] + "'," + row["Progression"] + "],");
}
```

You can see this on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ovk7nqf/):

[image: Correct labels]

If this doesn't work, then try posting the actual rendered JS on your page - if you're saying that the graph doesn't render at all you've probably got an error in the final JS - check your browser console for errors relating to miss closed strings, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing the columns backwards.

Here, you've specified "Progression" first, then "Course":

```
strScript.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>  
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']}); </script>  

        <script type='text/javascript'>  

        function drawChart() {         
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
        ['Progression', 'Course'],");
```

But then your loop is appending "Course" data in the "Progression" column, and "Progression Data" in the "Course" column:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsChartData.Rows)
{
    strScript.Append("['" + row["Course"] + "'," + row["Progression"] + "],");
}
```

Flip them around. Also, accessing a column in a `DataRow` returns the value as an `object`, so it probably can't tell what the underlying value is supposed to be. Parse the numerical value.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsChartData.Rows)
{
    strScript.Append("[" + int.Parse(row["Progression"]) + ",'" + row["Course"] + "'],");
}
```

One more thing.. according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable), you should pass `false` into the call to `arrayToDataTable()` to indicate the first row contains labels. Change this:

```
strScript.Append("]);");
```

To this:

```
strScript.Append("], false);");
```

Comment: I already tried this and for some strange reason the chart doesn't even get displayed :/

Comment: I get this error `Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string`

Comment: Hmm, no mention of the `false` parameter in [their example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) though :( But I think all @Izzy needs to do is flip the labels around and everything else should work as expected - there must be a JS error causing the graphs not to load.

Answer (score -1):

You're adding parameters in a bad way. ( I suppose you were writting desktop apps and you were using Parameters.AddWithValue() method. It's slightly different than Parameters.Add()

Try like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;
```

Comment: Actually You missunderstood me. Try to change the way You're adding paramaters to the way i showed You(it will work in asp). If it won't help, I try to figure out what is going on here :)

Comment: Exactly the same issue

Comment: Did You try to print values retrieved from the database ? Maybe They're just inverted so it can cause the issue.